# SQL Output if row exists, insert and output if it does not exist

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I basically want to insert something and use the OUTPUT function to get some values out of the inserted line. That's easy.
But I also want my query to get these values even if there has nothing been inserted because the primary already exists.

```
DECLARE @existingId bigint;
IF EXISTS(SELECT @existingId = Id FROM MyTable WHERE Name = @Name)
    OUTPUT @existingId;
    RETURN;
INSERT INTO MyTable (Name) OUTPUT INSERTED.Id VALUES (@Name);
```

This just always gives me `Incorrect syntax near '='.`

Any ideas how to achieve this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`output` takes a table, not a value.  So the code you are striving to write should look more like this:

```
DECLARE @out table (existingid bigint);

INSERT INTO @out(existingid)
    SELECT Id FROM MyTable WHERE Name = @Name;

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @out)
    RETURN;

INSERT INTO MyTable (Name)
    OUTPUT INSERTED.Id INTO @out
    VALUES (@Name);
```

This code, however, has race conditions.  Because someone could insert `Name` between the check for the existence and the `insert`.  To really fix this, you should use `try`/`catch` and have a unique index on `name`. Here is an example of the code:

```
DECLARE @out table (existingid bigint);

BEGIN TRY
    INSERT INTO MyTable (Name)
        OUTPUT INSERTED.Id INTO @out
        VALUES (@Name);

    RETURN
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH -- assume there is a duplicate although there could be other problems
    INSERT INTO @out(existingid)
        SELECT Id FROM MyTable WHERE Name = @Name;
END CATCH;
```

The following code creates the unique index:

```
create unique index idx_mytable_name on mytable(name);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are missing  A opening and closing parenthesis, try:

```
DECLARE @existingId bigint;
IF EXISTS(SELECT @existingId =( Id FROM MyTable WHERE Name = @Name))
    OUTPUT @existingId;
    RETURN;
INSERT INTO MyTable (Name) OUTPUT INSERTED.Id VALUES (@Name);
```